# For each RxJS Operator you import, you should now import from 'rxjs/operators' and use the pipe operator`

Tags: angular, rxjs

- I am upgrading from angular 2 to angular 5
- I used the below link and did update.
  https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/
- doing each step one by one not sure how to update this step
  For each RxJS Operator you import, you should now import from 'rxjs/operators' and use the pipe operator`.
- I have used Rxjs like this in my code base but not sure how to change it

https://hastebin.com/rezelikuku.cs

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class playerService {
    public tabvaluechange;
    public copiedEvent;
    private searchBtnEvent = new Subject<any>();
    private changeEvent = new Subject<any>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the current new import statements:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

They use the new lettable (sometimes called pipeable) operators. You use them like this:

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productsUrl)
                    .pipe(
                        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
                        catchError(this.handleError)
                    );
}
```

So instead of chaining them in a fluent syntax, you use the Observable's pipe method and pass in each operator to execute.

**Note:** The new operators could not conflict with JavaScript key words, so `do` is now `tap` and `catch` is now `catchError`. `map` is still `map`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

should be :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

and operators could be like this: (depending on the operator that you need)

```
import { map, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Comment: As of rxjs 6, imports should be done directly from `rxjs`, not `rxjs/Observable` etc.

Comment: Yes but version 6 is not the latest stable version, and should not be used in production. See here for more info: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS. Furthemore, the latest version of Angular does not ship with Rxjs 6, so rxjs/Observable should be used, not rxjs only

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to say your answer was wrong. I just wanted to provide some additional perspective for future visitors.